# Displaying has_many through association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small app that allows the user to track their holdings for a portfolio by adding their own stock picks to it. I have built the associations to be the following:

```
stock.rb 
has_many :portfolio_stocks
has_many :portfolios, through: :portfolio_stocks

portfolio.rb 
has_many :portfolio_stocks
has_many :stocks, throough: :portfolio_stocks

portfolio_stocks.rb
belongs_to :stock
belongs_to :portfolio
```

I am having trouble in my new template for adding the stock to the portfolio. This is what the stocks_controller action is

```
def create
portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
@stock = portfolio.stock.create(stock_params)
end

# GET /stocks/new
def new
@portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
@stock = Stock.new
end
```

and my `new.html.erb` template

```
<center>
<div class="container">
<div class="card-body">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
<%= link_to 'Home', portfolios_path %>
</li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active">Create</li>
</ol>
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {stock: @stock, portfolio: @portfolio}%>   
</div>
</div>
</center>
```

which renders the _form partial

```
<%= form_for(stock, url: portfolio_stocks_path(portfolio)) do |f| %>
<% if stock.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(stock.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this portfolio 
from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% stock.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
<li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.text_field :symbol, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', 
placeholder: "Enter a ticker" %>
</div>
```

I keep getting the error

> can't find Portfolio with "id" =

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 >"stock"=>{"symbol"=>"FB",
 >"sector"=>"Tech",
 >"high"=>"123",
 >"low"=>"123",
 >"price"=>"123"},
 >"commit"=>"Add Stock",
 >"portfolio_id"=>"1"}
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you update the question with the related server log for the error?

Comment: I noted a typo, `throough`? Is it a mistake in your code, or in the question?

Answer (score 0):

> can't find Portfolio with "id" =

Going by with the assumption and by looking at this piece of code `portfolio_stocks_path(portfolio))`, I believe you are using **nested routes** for `portfolios` and `stocks`. If so, that explains the reason for the error.

If you run `rake routes`, you would see

```
portfolio_stocks      POST   /portfolios/:portfolio_id/stocks(.:format)        stocks#create
new_portfolio_stock   GET    /portfolios/:portfolio_id/stocks/new(.:format)    stocks#new
```

That means a `Portfolio` instance should be accessed with `params[:portfolio_id]` not with `params[:id]` in the `stocks_controller`. That said, you should change the `new` and `create` methods like so

```
def create
  portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:portfolio_id])
  @stock = portfolio.stocks.create(stock_params) #fixed the invalid syntax
end

# GET /stocks/new
def new
  @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:portfolio_id])
  @stock = Stock.new
end
```

Also notice that I've changed `portfolio.stock.create(stock_params)` to `portfolio.stocks.create(stock_params)` because with how your associations are setup `portfolio.stock.create(stock_params)` would be an **invalid syntax** and will *raise an exception*.

Comment: Thanks for answer Pavan! Yes I am using a nested route in the way that you say. I am still getting the same error through when I try to create a new stock for the portfolio even after I made the updates you suggested.

Comment: @JosephParker Can you update the question with the `params` that appear in the server log when you submit the form?

Comment: @JosephParker I've updated my answer. As per your `params`, it should be `Portfolio.find(params[:portfolio_id])` in `create` method too